# Can I build a docker container based on the host file system?

Tags: docker

I want to use docker for its network isolation, but that's all.

More specifically, I want to run two programs and only allow network access a certain port on the one program if the connection is relayed through the second program.  The one program is a VNC server and the second program is a Websocket relay with a custom authentication scheme.

So, I'm thinking about putting them both in a container and using docker port mappings to control their network access.

Can I setup docker so that I use the host's file system directly?  I'd like to do things like access an .Xauthority file and create UNIX domain sockets (the VNC server does this).  I know that I could mount the host filesystem in the container, but it'd be simpler to just use it directly as the container's filesystem.  I think.

Is this possible?  Easy?

Comment: Yes it is possible! :-)

Comment: Curious on how that would be accomplished so I'm keeping an eye on this topic. For the structure and internal communication you can use docker compose. This will make configuration a bit easier (plus, you can define a "network" in the compose file). You will still need some network config on your host machine (firewall settings etc.).

Comment: IMHO it's the wrong tool, and you'll probably find it easier to manually set up Linux network namespaces if that's literally the only Docker-oriented functionality you want.  It's also a little easier to control access to Unix sockets if that's an option to communicate between the two programs.

Comment: @mahatmanich, ...and answering the question is easy!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every container is based on an image that packages the filesystem layers. The filesystem namespace cannot be disabled in docker (unlike the network, pid, and other namespaces you can set to "host").

For your requirements, if you do not want to use host volume mounts, and do not want to package the application in an image, then you would be better off learning network namespaces in the Linux kernel which docker uses to implement container isolation. The [ip netns](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) command is a good place to start.

Comment: This is the solution I'm looking for.  I was already wondering how docker implemented its network isolation.  That's why I posted some additional information about what I was trying to accomplish (always a good idea).